# Error transforming XML

Tags: java, xml, transformation

I have a problem parsing an xml, actually transforming it.

The error I get is:

```
ERROR:  'Namespace for prefix 'SOAP-ENV' has not been declared.'
Jul 8, 2011 3:24:54 PM kumar.runs.start$2 run
SEVERE: null
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Namespace for prefix 'SOAP-ENV' has not been declared.
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:716)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:313).........
```

The code I use is:

```
    SAXParserFactory saxFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance(); 
    SAXParser parser = saxFactory.newSAXParser(); 
    XMLReader reader = new XMLTrimFilter(parser.getXMLReader()); 

    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance(); 
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(); 
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no"); 
    DOMResult result = new DOMResult(); 
    SAXSource ss = new SAXSource(reader, is);
    transformer.transform(ss, result); 
    return (Document)result.getNode();
```

XMLTrimFilter is custom implementation, extends XMLFilterImpl.

Also I came across this:

[A Bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4641035)

but it is a rather old issue.
Does anybody have an idea how to fix it?

Thanks!

[Edit:
the xml:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header />
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <swp:addOwnRet xmlns:swbep="urn:SWBEP">
                  <apples>33</apples>
                  <bucket>
                    <orange>5</orange>
                    <banana>5</banana>
                  </bucket>
            </swp:addOwnRet>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

]

Edit 2:

XMLTrimFilter:

```
package kumar.srcs;
```

import java.io.CharArrayWriter;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl;

public class XMLTrimFilter extends XMLFilterImpl{

```
private CharArrayWriter contents = new CharArrayWriter(); 

public XMLTrimFilter(XMLReader parent){ 
    super(parent); 
} 
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException{ 
    writeContents(); 
    super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, atts); 
}

public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length){ 
    contents.write(ch, start, length); 
} 

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException{ 
    writeContents(); 
    super.endElement(uri, localName, qName); 
} 

public void ignorableWhitespace(char ch[], int start, int length){} 

private void writeContents() throws SAXException{ 
    char ch[] = contents.toCharArray(); 
    if(!isWhiteSpace(ch)) 
        super.characters(ch, 0, ch.length); 
    contents.reset(); 
} 

private boolean isWhiteSpace(char ch[]){ 
    for(int i = 0; i<ch.length; i++){ 
        if(!Character.isWhitespace(ch[i])) 
            return false; 
    } 
    return true; 
}
```

}

Comment: Without more information the obvious place to look is XMLTrimFilter... can you post the source for it? Is it removing the NS declarations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have enough information, but the first two things I would suspect are:

1. The input XML doesn't declare the namespace properly; i.e. it is invalid XML.
2. There is a bug in your custom `XMLTrimFilter` class.

---

The Sun bug is against a really old version of JAXP and was fixed a long time ago.  And it doesn't much resemble your case ... to me.

---

The XML that you pasted is missing a namespace declaration, and will give errors if you try to parse it with a validating namespace aware XML parser.  This could be the cause of your problems, though the error message doesn't seem right.  A more likely cause is your custom filter, IMO.

Comment: 1 - It is definitely not a problem of the structure of the XML, I've used this XML many times - the problem comes when I try to transform it.  2 - Nope, it is not mine implementation but I know for sure that it works ok.

Comment: @karla - well if you are not going to show them to us, I don't fancy your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: more information - I'm trying to run this example: http://www.jroller.com/santhosh/entry/xml_viewer_with_swing and this one: http://www.jroller.com/santhosh/entry/xml_viewer_with_swing_part

Comment: Could you add the XML document for which the transformer throws this exception? Even if it's structurally sound, there might be a namespace problem. Some parsers may process it properly if they're namespace-unaware.

Comment: XML declaration is optional, there is no requirement it has to be included.

Comment: I stopped using that XMLTrimFilter - things got better.

Answer (score 0):

After checking your XML in a suitable editor, I noticed that there's no namespace defined for the prefix "swp", the one that element `addOwnRet` falls under. It's possible that for SOAP usage purposes this is alright (I'm not very familiar with the protocol), but for an XSLT processor this is simply an XML document and nothing more.

Now, your exception said "namespace for prefix **SOAP-ENV** has not been declared". It says nothing about "swp". But it's not impossible that there's some bug in the exception reporting that puts the wrong prefix name in the message.

It would make sense that other processing doesn't fail, since an undeclared namespace prefix makes an XML document invalid, but doesn't necessarily make it non-well-formed. An XSLT processor must make use of namespace scopes to properly determine which templates an input node fits, so it requires the URI that the prefix is bound to.

If you can manually supply an XML document to your transformation, I suggest sending it through without that "swp" prefix, or simply declare some random namespace URI for it. Then see if this still happens. It's also possible that `swbep` should be used and the `swp` is a mistake.
The closing tag for the document is also missing, but I assume that simply fell off when pasting it into your post.

Comment: Thank you! Sounds reasonable - I'll try it very soon!

Comment: I tried out your suggestions, but I got the same result. I also tried with very basic xml - example by w3 - nothing..